# Como manejar dos datatables en ajax enviados desde WebMethod con asp.net c#

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net

Hola a todos espero me puedan guiar a resolver este problema. Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que me regresa dos select. Uno es para llenar el Grid y el otro es para mostrar una imagen.

Este es mi WebMethod donde concateno mis dos dataTables en la variables datos.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string Personas(int id_Persona, string Sucursal, int id_Rol) 
    {

        Transacciones t = new Transacciones();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable tabla_Persona = new DataTable();
        DataTable tabla_imagenProceso = new DataTable();
        ds = t.Mostrar_Persona(id_Persona, Sucursal, id_Rol);
        tabla_Persona = ds.Tables[0];            
        tabla_imagenProceso = ds.Tables[1];
        string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_Persona,Formatting.Indented);
        datos += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_imagenProceso, Formatting.Indented);

        return datos; 

    }
```

Aqui tengo mi codigo ajax.Trabajo con el JxqGrid con columnas dinamicas. Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo manejar las dos dataTables que retorne en mi WebMethod en ajax para mostrar mi Grid y mostrar la imagen?

```js
function obtener_intervalo() {


    var persona = $("[id*=ddlPersona]").val();
    var Sucursal = "";
    var id_Rol = 1;
    
    if (persona != 0) {
    
    var valores;
    var datafields_persona = new Array();
    var columns_persona = new Array();
    var columnsArray = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "frmPersona.aspx/Personas",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{id_Persona:"' + persona + '",Sucursal:"' + Sucursal + '",id_Rol:"' + id_Rol + '"}',
            async: false,

            success: function(data) {
                
                if (data != '') {

                    valores = data.d; 
                    valores = JSON.parse(valores);                   

                    for (var i in valores[0]) {
                        datafields_persona.push({ name: i });
                        columns_persona.push({ text: i, datafield: i, width: 200 });
                        
                    }

                    for (var j = 1; j < columnspersona.length; j++) {
                        columnsArray.push(columns_persona[j]);
                        
                    }

                }

                var gridSource =
                {
                    datatype: "json",                   
                    localdata: valores,
                    async: false
                };
```

Comment: No se puede usar `DataTable` con `json` tienes que definir clases. No se que tan dinamico quieres las columnas pero quizas podrias resolverlo usando herencia de clases y serializar en base a estas segun sea el caso

Comment: Hola @LeandroTuttini mi resultado de datos al concatenarlos me devuelve dos arreglos de objetos json. ¿Sabes como podria manejar esos dos arreglos en el ajax?